# How to create Timer Progress bar as shown below in GIF?

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari

I want to create animated progress as below, but the thing is it is not working properly on safari browser

[image: Timer can be dynamic]

The css property which I used is:

```css
.prgoressBar {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        height: 22px;
        background-color:#BBBBBB;
        overflow: hidden;
      }

      .prgoressBar div {
        height: 100%;
        text-align: right;
        padding: 0;
        line-height: 22px; /* same as #progressBar height if we want text middle aligned */
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #185A8D;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        color:#fff;
        -webkit-transition: width 1s linear;
            -moz-transition: width 1s linear;
            -o-transition: width 1s linear;
            transition: width 1s linear;
        
      }
```

```html
<div id="QM_progressBar" class="prgoressBar">
</div>
```

Comment: you tried to add style to div inside `.progressBar` but you have no div inside

Comment: Do you have problem yet?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the 'transform: scaleX()' instead of changing the width. Transform uses to run better with transition, maybe that's why Safari is freaking out.

I don't have Safari installed right now, so please check if this codepen works: https://codepen.io/thiagoberrutti/pen/GRmLzZK.

In the codepen I used transition but in this snippet I tried with animations instead, see if one of them can work on Safari:

```css
    .progress-container{
  
      width:500px;
      height:22px;
      border:5px solid #ccc;
    }

    .progress{
      width:100%;
      transform-origin:left;
      height:100%;
      background-color:#185A8D;  
      animation: timer var(--time) linear forwards;
    }

    @keyframes timer{
      0%{
        transform:scaleX(1)
      }
  
      100%{
        transform: scaleX(0);
      }
    }

        .progress-container{
  
          width:500px;
          height:22px;
          border:5px solid #ccc;
        }

        .progress{
          width:100%;
          transform-origin:left;
          height:100%;
          background-color:#185A8D;  
          animation: timer var(--time) linear;
        }

        @keyframes timer{
          0%{
            transform:scaleX(1)
          }
  
          100%{
            transform: scaleX(0);
          }
        }
```

```html
<div class="progress-container">
  <div class="progress" style="--time:5s"></div>
</div>
```